# Storing large amounts of IOT data in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My current app (built on Flutter for Android/iOS and Angular for Web) utilizes Bluetooth and USB to connect to devices and send data retrieved over to Firestore. Here, I have created a collection called 'scans' which stores all the data.

The data contains (about 10KB) userID, companyID, stats, IoT info and much more which can be queried on the web/mobile dashboard based on user input. Currently there are around 23,000 documents inside 'scans'.

I wanted to get a better understanding of the best practices of structuring data inside firebase and how the querying speed is effected by the number of total documents in a collection. Till now, it takes about 1-2 seconds for it to download the correct documents, but I imagine that this might not scale well with, say 20 million scans or more. What strategy is to be used for Firestore in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of documents in a collection does *not* affect the speed with which queries are executed. That's the main performance guarantee that Firestore makes, and it's quite relevant to your use-case.

The reason Firestore can make this guarantee is that it doesn't have to perform full index scans for any of the queries it supports. And the reason Firestore doesn't support some of the queries you may be used to from other databases, is because it can't meet the performance guarantee for such queries.

So: you don't have to worry about having 10s of thousands, 100s of thousands of even millions of document in the collection. If retrieving a certain number of document takes a certain amount of time on 10K documents, it will always take that same amount of time even when there are millions of documents.

Comment: Thanks mate. I wrote 1 million docs in firebase and although it costed me $0.10, I was able to validate that it didn't change the read time. Also, for making an IoT database, would you recommend some alternatives? I've heard that since Firebase Realtime Database is free for unlimited writes, would that be better for this application? Also, I've considered using AWS amplify and wanted to get some concrete differences between the two databases for performance and pricing metrics, online opinions are very mixed. I'm asking from an IoT perspective

Comment: Technology recommendations are off-topic, as they're highly subjective. But for choosing between Firebase's two databases, have a look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore